# Fresh Crawling for dynamic data

Tags: web-crawler, dynamic-data

I am trying to write a crawler to crawl information from a website which contains around 15 GB of data. I crawl the information and store it in my database. Now new pages continue to get added to the site every week and at the same time old pages get updated. Does it mean I have to recrawl the whole 15 GB of data and build my database allover again every time some edit occurs. What is the simplest way to deal with that problem? How does Google News work because they face the similar problem of information getting updated across the globe? Till now I have found the following research paper on this topic:

http://oak.cs.ucla.edu/~cho/papers/cho-tods03.pdf

And is it always necessary to write your custom crawler for that purpose? Cant I use Scrapy or Nutch?

Comment: Personally, in my crawler, I prioritize crawling new pages over re-crawling old pages which have been updated. I wrote my code in a way that I only need to partially update my database when a page changes.

Comment: but imagine you are crawling some amount of data from websites like imdb, where the ratings changes everyday, and new movies keep getting added...how do you deal with that?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't see what the issue is? Most crawlers have to deal with updates...

Comment: my point is do i have to parse every page and reconstruct my database every time my crawler crawls across imdb? Wouldn't that be a costly overhead?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do in Nutch is use AdaptiveFetchSchedule as explained [here](http://pascaldimassimo.com/2010/06/11/how-to-re-crawl-with-nutch/). It lets Nutch re-crawl a page, detect if it was changed in the meantime, and adapt the schedule to more frequently re-crawl pages that change more often, and vice versa.
Of course, you could just check the Last-Modified headers if they exist and are to be trusted and simply not re-crawl if the dates are before the last crawl. Not sure if this is already implemented in Nutch when detecting the changes or if some hash-based solution is used, but it doesn't sound too hard to do manually if need be.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will mark it as accepted once I actually implement the same on Nutch. I am working with the imdb data and the last modified header on imdb generally shows the current time because of the news updates on the pages I believe.

Comment: If the page has constant changes, due to ads or whatever, no matter the algorithm used, it will always detect changes... Maybe you should add element blacklisting into the equation. I made a simple plugin for that: https://github.com/veggen/nutch-element-selector